# I have old Angular 1 code where i set div styles how would that work in Angular 11

Tags: angular

So i have been working on updating an old project and i need to set the style of an array where each point has a different positon. The Divs all have an id = obj.id and i need to set the left and top values.

```
    $(arr).each(function(idx,obj){
            var e = $('#'+obj.id);
            e.css('left',obj.cx);
            e.css('top',obj.cy);
```

In the old code we get the array id and set it to var. But i cant seem to make that work for Angular 11. how would i do that?

Comment: that looks more like jQuery than AngularJS.

Comment: There is no Angular 1. There is AngularJs and Angular >= 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i came up with a solution:

```
[ngStyle]="{'top': d.cy, 'left': d.cx}"
```

i just added a ngStyle element on the div where i run through the array and every point gets his own position